# Laravel always return the error bag of an Validation error in json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm developing an api that should also provide messages about the validation problems.

When "hardcoding" validators I'm doing something like this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
}
```

this works nice - however I want a "generic" solution to basically catch all ValidationExceptions and do the same as above.

I already tried to play around in the render function of `Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    $message = $exception->getMessage();

    if (is_object($message)) {
        $message = $message->toArray();
    }

    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return response()->json($message, 400);
    }

    ...
}
```

However I can't find a proper way of returning the actual relevant data that I want

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda dumb - actually laravel already provided what I want. Handler extends ExceptionHandler which does:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $e = $this->prepareException($e);

    if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
    }

    return $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
}
```

and convertValidationExceptionToResponse :

```
    if ($e->response) {
        return $e->response;
    }

    $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput(
        $request->input()
    )->withErrors($errors);
```

So exactly what I wanted

Comment: If you always want it to return json, you can do the validation the way the docs say: `$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages)` and override the method `buildFailedValidationResponse` in `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` trait so that it always builds a json response.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
 if ($request->wantsJson() && (str_contains('api/v1/register', $request->path())) || (str_contains('api/v1/login', $request->path())) ) {
$errors = null ;
if($exception->validator){
$errors = $exception->validator->errors();
}
return response()->json([
'status' => 422,'success'=> false,'message'=>''. $exception->getMessage() ,'error'=> "" . $errors
            ], 422);
}
return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Instead explain _why_ your code solves the ops question.